# In IIS 7, can you bind more than one SSL certificate to a single website / IP address / port number?

Tags: iis-7, ssl-certificate

I'm being tasked with binding multiple SSL certificates to the same website.

I have a single website with a single domain that the client wants to bind multiple SSL certs from different CAs. So www.mydomain.com needs to have multiple SSL certs bound to it.

I don't think this is possible but is there a way this can be done?

Comment: I literally googled your exact question: http://forums.iis.net/t/1173794.aspx/1

Comment: @Ruirize That link is not about my situation. I have a single website with a single domain that the client wants to bind multiple SSL certs from different CAs. So www.mydomain.com needs to have multiple SSL certs bound to it.

Comment: Do the multiple SSL certs all have unique common names, (i.e. site.domain1.com, site.domain2.com, etc)?

Comment: For what reason would anyone want to do that.. you can have multiple certificates, but you can only realistically use one at a time. You can also have multiple CAs, but how do you decide which certificate to set up your session with?

Comment: @NickW, I don't know why anyone would want to do this either but I was curious whether the point about binding multiple SSL certs was for supporting multiple CA certs using the same www.mydomain.com name or multiple certs using different names. Just to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: As he states it, one domain, one website, but they want multiple certificates. Maybe they could put the same site on different servers, load balance/ proxy it in front and each back end server has it's own certificate.. still seems pointless.

Comment: @NickW The reason is a purely political one. I'm pretty sure the request is not possible, but my area is in development and not server admin. So I need something with a little more "authority" than my "say so". They'll want to see some type of proof, link, article, ... that their request is not possible. Or ... if I am wrong, then I hope someone can point my in the right direction.

Comment: I didn't think you were the one responsible, but I think more than anything else, you're just going to have to point to the word "certificate" instead of certificates. Things like this are close, but are trying to put multiple "faces" on a single site, for per customer branding: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Forefrontedgegeneral/thread/80faf11d-a2dc-49dc-bb24-e24273f50f22

Comment: Here's something a bit more definitive on the no side: http://serverfault.com/questions/437466/multiple-ssl-certificates-to-access-one-asp-net-application-in-iis

Comment: @NickW Thanks for the extra links. The server fault link was close, but they also went into multiple domains. Still, I'm feeling more and more that the reason such a definitive link doesn't exist is because, like you mentioned already, the request is pointless. The client will need to decide on which CA they want to go with. I can't see where the technology will allow each of them to use their "favorite" CA. I'm embarrassed having posted this question, but I try to accommodate the client as far as I can. But I can't accommodate the impossible. Thanks again.

Comment: Well, you could set up multiple servers, each with its own certificate, a single domain name, and do round robin DNS. Good luck convincing them.

Comment: @NickW And if the client is *that* set on having different CAs, your load balanced suggestion sounds like it would work. If you write it up as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is one way to do it, although I think that it is an abomination.

You could request the certificates, then install each one of a different server which is configured to serve up the same site with the same domain name. The next part could vary slightly, you could either use [Round Robin DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS), but that requires multiple public IPs, and will have issues with fault tolerance(there's a bit written on the page about the shortcomings). You could also set up a load balancer/proxy, which doesn't require that the servers have public IPs, but it is another layer of complexity.

Best of luck convincing them that it isn't how HTTPS works.